# passing small int data from SQL to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not sure how to approach this. Currently I am getting a column from my database that is entitled "ITEMNMBR" which is of type "char" and then pass it to a textBox. That part of my code works fine but what I want to do now is to get another column and pass it to another comboBox. The column which is named "ITEMTYPE" is of smallint. What am I doing wrong?

```
while (dr.Read())
            {
                string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMNMBR"));
                textBox2.Text = cari_code;
                string intFromSmallInt = dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMTYPE"));
                textBox12.Text = intFromSmallInt; 

                //con.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: This actually wasn't a duplicate. What u need to do is just add `Convert.toString` before your `dr.GetInt16` You should be good after that.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something simple.